# how to run a Kruskal-Wallis Test in R, with 3 columns of data to include

Tags: r, kruskal-wallis

using R to run a Kruskal-Wallis test to see if there is a difference between 4 species plot counts, over time.

Code I'm using is:-

```
kruskal.test(Plot_count$SPIECES ~ Time2, data = AMO_data_long)
```

But don't trust the results as appear to only test if there is a difference of plot counts over time and not test the frequency of plot counts **between** species over time. The data set has a column for species, time and plot count. how do you group plot count per species and test the difference in species frequency over time?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HA3XC.png)

Using SPIECES, Time2 and Plot_count in code.

suggestions welcomed.

P.S. SPIECES is spelt incorrectly but it works :p

Comment: Please dont add your data as an image, but instead edit your question to include both datasets you reference (`Plot_count` and `AMO_data_long `) as reproducible code.

Comment: Have you looked at the other posts regarding the K-W tests that demonstrate how to use it properly?  Also, posting data sets in image is highly deprecated onSO.

Comment: After 4 hours waiting for a response , I’m voting to close as needing further details.